# Why FeatureNotSupportedException is being thrown even though I have the feature in my physical device(OnePlus AC2001 Android11.0 - API-30)?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement official [documentation of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-a-mobile-app-with-xamarin-forms/5-exercise-create-phone-number-translator-app). When I am trying to take numbers to the dialing page it is throwing the exception `FeatureNotSupportedException`  which states as per the documentation

> Exception that occurs when an attempt is made to use a feature on a platform that does not support it.

I am using OnePlus AC2001 Android11.0 - API-30 and I believe all phone must contain this basic functionality of dialing through `PhoneDialer.Open(translatedNumber)`

```
  async void OnCall(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (await this.DisplayAlert(
        "Dial a Number",
        "Would you like to call " + translatedNumber + "?",
        "Yes",
        "No"))
            {
                try
                {
                    PhoneDialer.Open(translatedNumber);
                }
                catch (ArgumentNullException)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Unable to dial", "Phone number was not valid.", "OK");
                }
                catch (FeatureNotSupportedException)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Unable to dial", "Phone dialing not supported.", "OK");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // Other error has occurred.
                    await DisplayAlert("Unable to dial", "Phone dialing failed.", "OK");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

did you read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/phone-dialer?tabs=android)?

> If your project's Target Android version is set to Android 11 (R API
> 30) you must update your Android Manifest with queries that are used
> with the new package visibility requirements.
>
> Open the AndroidManifest.xml file under the Properties folder and add
> the following inside of the manifest node:

```
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
    <data android:scheme="tel"/>
  </intent>
</queries>
```